# Slidedown not working with newly created html

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

```
<div id="usu" ></div>
```

Then I have script that is supposed to add content to that:

```
<script>
  var haelisaanro = 10
  function haelisaa() {
      $.getJSON("/json/index_oikea.aspx?usu=1", function (data) {

          var items = [];
          items.push("<div id='rivit" + haelisaanro + "' >");
          $.each(data, function (key, val) {
              items.push("<div class=\"col-md-12 column nlnyR  \"><table><tr><td><div class=\"ot\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"><\/span><\/div><\/td><td><a href='" + key + "'>" + val + "</a><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/div>");
          });
          items.push("</div>");

          $("#usu").append(items.join(""));
          $('#rivit' + haelisaanro).hide();
          $('#rivit' + +haelisaanro).slideDown("slow", function () {
              // Animation complete.
          });
      });
      haelisaanro += 10;
  }
  </script>
```

I have this on pageload too:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#oikear" ).load( "/index_oikea.aspx", function() {
          $( "#oikear2" ).load( "/index_oikea2.aspx", function() {
                    //alert('lahataanTop of thing hit top of viewport.');
            });

        });

});




</script>
```

index_oikea.aspx is loaded to #oikear div. Loaded content has `<div id="usu" ></div>`  in the middle of loded content index_oikea.aspx.

It does fill that are "usu" with data, but there is no slidedown animation on it.

I tryed to add height attribute css to id='rivit'. It seemed like it needs the height to work, but I could not manage to make it work with right height size.

I think the main reason this is not working is that browser can not calculate the height of dynamicly added content somehow...?

**If I changethe code... Add this style:**

```
<style>
.dplno{display: none;}
</style>
```

change to this:

```
   items.push("<div class=\"col-md-12 column nlnyR dplno  \"><table><tr><td><div class=\"ot\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-play\"><\/span><\/div><\/td><td><a href='" + key + "'>" + val + "</a><\/td><\/tr><\/table><\/div>");
```

and change this:

```
$( '.dplno' ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
```

Now every div line is sliding out, but every line is sliding one by one. I needed to slide all those lines at onece.

Comment: i will be good, if you create a fiddle for this.

Comment: Get rid of the extra plus first in `+ +haelisaanro` :)

Comment: Instead of using escape character you can use ' single quote.

Comment: `+ +` on a numeric (which `haelisaanro` *is*) will only convert it to positive before concatenating it *so is harmless but best removed*. If `haelisaanro` was not a number you would get `#rivitNaN` :)

Comment: Yes there were small typo but it does not affect. Slideonw function is not sliding anything, it just shows up. If I add css to "<div id='rivit" + haelisaanro + "' >") , like style="height:200px". then the slider works. only problem that the dynamicly added lenght/height is not same everytime and I have no clue how to calculate it dynamicly.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating with + + sign, that may be problem

```
$('#rivit' + +haelisaanro).slideDown("slow", function () {
              // Animation complete.
          });
```

Thus it may be forming wrong id.

Change to this:

```
$('#rivit'+haelisaanro).slideDown("slow", function () {
              // Animation complete.
          });
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you always catch me :) But OP is not responding.

Comment: That's what I'm here for :)

Comment: It was a small typo. It does not make any change at the end. still slidedown is not sliding, just showing up. Could the problem be that <div id="usu" ></div>  is loaded dynamicly with jquery load before user activetes function haelisaa()

Comment: somehow browser is not knowing the height of added data.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the div before applying slideDown. That might be causing your issue.
You should first define animation and then hide the div.

```
$('#rivit' + +haelisaanro).slideDown("slow", function () {
    // Animation complete.
});
$('#rivit' + haelisaanro).hide();
```

Comment: I removed completly hide part $('#rivit' + haelisaanro).hide(); No effect. SlideDown is not sliding any things it just shows everything instantly.